# SSH connection slow on OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm experiencing extremly slow ssh connections on my new Macbook Pro w/ OS X 10.9.5 connecting to (mostly) ubuntu 12.x or 14.x servers.

Login is fast, but when I want to input the first command (like e.g. `vim example.txt`) it gets stuck at `v` ... `i` ... `m` every character for more than 5-10 seconds. No way to work like this.

Googling "slow ssh" only shows entries that are having problems connecting/logging into the remote machine (which is fast for me) but not after the connection is established.

What could be reason for this? Machine or internet provider/router config?
Or how could I best debug this issue?

*** update 1 ***

pinging my server (hosted vserver in germany) from home using WIFI looks good - but sshing still is unbearable.

```
PING myserver.com (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=32.906 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=34.263 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=32.325 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=33.007 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=32.789 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=32.012 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=53 time=32.992 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=53 time=32.493 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=53 time=33.349 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=53 time=32.927 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=53 time=32.149 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=53 time=33.353 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=53 time=33.465 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=53 time=33.612 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=53 time=33.313 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=53 time=33.549 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=53 time=33.325 ms
^C
--- myserver.com ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 17 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 32.012/33.049/34.263/0.562 ms
```

*** update 2 ***

sshing from the macbook to my own linux server in the same (home-)network is fast. strange? has to be something with the ISP?

*** update 3 ***

installed putty on my win7 machine and sshed into the same machine - still super slow. same WIFI.

Comment: First, check ping delays and losses (just ping the servers) , and paste the result.

Comment: Could you edit your question to describe the network between your macbook and these servers? Are you using a VPN? Are you connecting from your house to your office? How far apart are the servers physically? How long does it take to ping from one system to the other?

Comment: @ilkhd added the pings

Answer (score 0):

Looks like updating my Fritzbox's firmware from 
`FRITZ!OS 06.20` to `FRITZ!OS 06.23` fixes the problem.

At least for the moment. Maybe just restarting the router helped - will try and contact the guys from "fritz" to clear this up.